# Is it possible to pull and display a single landscape oriented image

Tags: images

I wanted to know if this is possible. I have gone through a lot of threads on the internet for this one and there does not seem to be one good solution. I run a business website based on wordpress and now there is this peculiar requirement wherein I need a hack/code to pull and display one single image ( from among the other images uploaded/attached to that post ).

Now the tricky part is that the image must be a horizontally/landscape oriented image only. And if it does not find a landscape image it may return nothing. Please let me know if need more clarifications.

If you must know, I already have a featured image.

Comment: @johannes. Your code seems to work. I took your code and pasted in my custom-functions.php and used the code below in my single.php and I was able to pull a url of the image. Now, what do I need to modify to the acutal image? thanks.

Comment: See the below usage example. If by "modify" you mean display it in a different size: CSS or the `img` tags `width` and `height` attribute are your friend. But that is for one a different issue and for another pure HTML/CSS.

Comment: @JohannesPille this code '<img src="<?php echo wpse_96012_landscape_image() ;?>" />' did the job. Now everything is perfect. You guys are good. Thank you.

Comment: While a "Thanks" is appreciated, be so kind as to tick the checkmark left of the answer if it solved your issue, such that others can later on tell that this issue is resolved. [Pay it forward](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sure, will do it right away. Also I was curious if I needed a single "vertical" image then what would change ?

Comment: The [`getimagesize` PHP function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) returns an array of 7 elements, the first two (at indices `0` and `1`, respectively) of which are the image's width and height. Hence, switching the indices in the below size comparison conditional (`if ( $size[1] >= ( $size[0] * $minimum_aspect_ratio ) )`) will make the function spit out "portrait" oriented images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Function to retrieve "landscape" oriented image

```
function wpse_96012_landscape_image() {

    /* global post object holding info about the current post */
    global $post;

    /* grab all images attached to the current post */
    $attached_images = get_children( array(
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image'
    ) );

    /* set minimum ratio between width / height, change to your liking */
    $minimum_aspect_ratio = 1.2;

    /*
     * iterate over attachments
     * get size, compare width & height
     * stop execution if an image with "landscape" dimensions is found
     */
    foreach( $attached_images as $image ) {
        $url = wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID );
        $size = getimagesize( $url );
        if ( $size[0] >= ( $size[1] * $minimum_aspect_ratio ) ) {
            return $url;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

### Later Usage

The above function will return the URL of the first image with an aspect ratio higher than or equal to the set minimum or `false` if none was found.

Hence, if you'd like to output the image on the condition of there being one, this is how you'd go about it:

```
$landscape_image_url = wpse_96012_landscape_image();
if ( $landscape_image_url ) {
    echo '<img alt="landscape image" src="' . $landscape_image_url . '" />';
}
```

### References

- [`get_children`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children) (WP)
- [`getimagesize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) (PHP)